# Where is this mountain with very striking bright colors?

Tags: china, where-on-earth, identify-this, mountains

[This blog](http://anintrospectiveworld.blogspot.ca/2012/06/danxia-landform-china.html) has an image from Zhangye, Province of Gansu, China.

[image]

This mountain is made of earths or stones in gradients of often bright colors, predominantly red but also yellows and blues.

However I cannot find directions anywhere to the landform, from Zhangye or anywhere else.

I suspect it's in the mountains SW of Zhangye, but I'd need either a satellite image or clear definitive instructions to be able to accept an answer.  Just "go to Zhangye" would not be enough :(

Comment: Have you tried emailing the blog owner?

Comment: @Grzenio - yeah, he just collects interesting pics from the internet, hasn't been there himself.

Comment: Strange, I was sure we'd already had this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you want in [Google Maps](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?vpsrc=6&ctz=0&ie=UTF8&t=h&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=215059858982352155417.0004b21d9a8781513bec9).

This Phenomenon is called [Danxia landform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danxia_landform). You can see more pics [here](http://english.sina.com/life/p/2009/0902/267787.html).

Comment: Looks like the particular image in the question had some creative colour adjustment applied, and you probably shouldn't expect to see blues like that picture. The photos [here](http://english.sina.com/life/p/2009/0902/267787.html) seem a bit more representative.

Comment: Thanks Halabi. I knew it was the Danxia, thus the tags, but wanted to find a location in Google Maps to confirm my suspicion that as jozzas points out, it's likely had some treatment to the colours. Still pretty spectacular!

Comment: I would love to go there. I am going to China soon but for three days only. It won't be enough to go there. If you ever go plz share the photos.